# Convert byte[] array TO sqldbtype.Varbinary using Dapper

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework, dapper

I've found a code snipped on the Internet that inserts a document as a byte array in the database. It is as follows:

```
    public void databaseFilePut(string varFilePath)
    {
        byte[] file;
        using (var stream = new FileStream(varFilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            using (var reader = new BinaryReader(stream))
            {
                file = reader.ReadBytes((int)stream.Length);
            }
        }

        //using (var varConnection = Locale.sqlConnectOneTime(Locale.slqDataConnectionDetails))
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        using (var sqlWrite = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO EXCEL_EM_BYTES (DOCUMENTO_BYTES) Values(@File)", connection))
        {
            sqlWrite.Parameters.Add("@File", SqlDbType.VarBinary, file.Length).Value = file;
            connection.Open();
            sqlWrite.ExecuteNonQuery();
            connection.Close();
        }
    }
```

Now, I have to apply that to Dapper/Entity framework, but so far, without success. What I got so far is as follows:

```
      public void InsereRegistroEmail(string a, string b, string c, byte[] anexoBytes)
    {
        //var cn = _context.Database.Connection;

        //cn.Execute(string.Format(QueriesSAC.InsereRegistroEmailBanco, motivoEmail, nomeGestor, corpoEmail, anexoBytes));

        var cn = _context.Database.Connection;
        //var A = new SqlParameter("@A", SqlDbType.VarBinary, anexoBytes.Length);
        //A.Value = anexoBytes;

        var sql =(string.Format("INSERT INTO [LOG_EMAIL] ([GSTOR_DSTNA] ,[ASSNT],[DATA_ENVIO],[CORPO_EMAIL],[ANEXO]) VALUES('{0}','{1}', GETDATE(),'{2}', @A)", a, b, c));
        var A = new DynamicParameters();
        A.Add("@A", anexoBytes, dbType: DbType.Binary, direction: ParameterDirection.Input);
        A.Get<DbType>("@A");
        cn.Execute(sql);
    }
```

The key line here is:

```
         sqlWrite.Parameters.Add("@File", SqlDbType.VarBinary, file.Length).Value = file;
```

As is the one that sets the data type to VarBinary. I really need some help here...

The file array is anexoBytes.

Comment: Not very familiar with Dapper, but don't you have to pass your parameters to `Execute` somehow?

Comment: @Crowcoder i believe the "sql" variable does that.

Comment: Thing is, i'm not trying to exec a proc. It's just a simple query. I couldn't make the Dapper example fit in there

Comment: There are other example in the documentation of using parameters. What you are doing is basically like what would happen in your ADO.Net example if you created SqlParameters but never added them to the SqlCommand.

Comment: Just try this, see what happens. Looks like the `Execute` extension method takes an object that is the parameters in the second position: `cn.Execute(sql, A);`

Comment: It says that the value of A is System.Byte[]. And the point of the sqlWrite.Parameters.Add("@File", SqlDbType.VarBinary, file.Length).Value = file; is to transform the byte array to Varbinary type. That's one of the main problems i'm having. I can't seem to do that in Dapper.

Comment: What says "the value of A is System.Byte[]"? Is it the `A.Get` line? Remove that line, it is just clutter. Looks like that should only be done after Execute AND if the parameter direction is Output.

Comment: EXCEL_EM_BYTES DDL ?Using `NVARCHAR(MAX)` or `FILESTREAM`. In ***Sql server 2016*** new features for JSON.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dapper can handle the assignments through an anonymous type that will take the place of the parameter values, so in your example, you would just change your SQL to define some parameterised SQL, then pass in the new object that contains the values for those parameters. This will automatically map the values up to their parameters and avoid the need to manually define them or perform string replacement on your SQL.

```
_connection.Execute("INSERT INTO [LOG_EMAIL] ([GSTOR_DSTNA] ,[ASSNT],[DATA_ENVIO],[CORPO_EMAIL],[ANEXO]) VALUES(@DstNa, @Assnt, GETDATE(), @CorpEmail, @Anexo",
            new { DstNa = a, Assnt = b, CorpEmail = c, Anexo = anexoBytes });
```

Comment: Valid for `NVARCHAR(MAX)`, `FILESTREAM` and ***new features JSON in Sql Server 2016*** ?